# Running script need two command with nohup

Tags: nohup

I want to run a script with `nohup` because it takes long time but it needs a password to run. how can I write the command using `nohup`. For example to run the script interactively I first run `php hat` and when it asks for a key or password I write `123456`.

I tried `nohup php hat & password` (for example 123) but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

When you run a command with `nohup`, the `stdin` is redirected from `/dev/null`. So you cannot use `nohup` and manually enter a password.

Depending up on the program that you're using, you can use redirections to enter the password:

```
$ nohup bash -c 'read; echo $REPLY' <<<'hello'
$ tail -1 nohup.out 
hello
```

So you could save your password in a file (say `password.txt`), and encrypt it using something like `gpg` with a password-protected private key (to get `password.txt.gpg`), and do:

```
gpg -d password.txt.gpg | nohup php hat
```

---

Or, you could use something like `screen`.

First start a `screen` session (this command actually either starts a session named `my-php-script-session`, or brings one that is already running to the foreground):

```
screen -D -RR -S my-php-script-session
```

Then in the shell that opens, run your command normally:

```
php hat
```

Enter your password, and then detach the `screen` session:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, followed by <kbd>d</kbd>.

You can re-attach it by running the first `screen` command again.